# How to remove class inside forEach loop when click event trigger Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to remove an `active` class from all elements. I already created the loop event. Inside the function the click event occurs where I wanted to remove a class from all `a` of that loop. But, it seems that I can't write this block of code correctly:

```
const links = document.querySelectorAll('.link-block a');
links.forEach(el => { 
   el.addEventListener('click', e => { 
      el.classList.remove('active');
   })
})
```

Full Code:

```js
const texts = document.querySelectorAll('.content p > span');
const links = document.querySelectorAll('.link-block a');
links.forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', e => {
    texts.forEach(text => text.classList.add('hidden'));
    const id = e.target.getAttribute('href');
    el.classList.remove('active');
    e.target.classList.add('active');
    document.querySelector(id).classList.remove('hidden');
  }); 
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.active {
  color: #f0f;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <section class="content">
    <p>
      <span id="content-1">Sample Text for Content 1.</span>
      <span id="content-2" class="hidden">Sample Text for Content 2.</span>
      <span id="content-3" class="hidden">Sample Text for Content 3.</span>
    </p>
  </section>
  <section class="link-block">
    <a href="#content-1" class="active">Content 1</a>
    <a href="#content-2">Content 2</a>
    <a href="#content-3">Content 3</a>
  </section>  
</section>
```

Comment: You've got the right answer now, but have you considered the d3 library for this kind of thing, as it avoids loops for the most part (sorry the code looks like cr*p in a comment)?
`const texts = d3.selectAll('.content p > span');
const links = d3.selectAll('.link-block a');
links.on ('click', (e, d) => {
    texts.classed('hidden', true);
    links.classed('active', false);
    d3.select(this).classed('active', true);
    const id = e.target.getAttribute('href');
    d3.select(id).classed('hidden', false);
});`

Comment: actually, I needed to do that with vanilla javascript. Implementation with d3 seems good. But, if I could use any other library, I would go with jQuery probably where I can achieve this feature like this way:  `$('.link-block a').on('click', function() {
 $('.link-block a').removeClass('active');
  $('.content p > span').addClass('hidden');
  const id = $(this).attr('href');
  $(id).removeClass('hidden');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need another loop to remove a class from each element.

`el.classList.remove('active');` in your code was referring to the current element, not to the collection of elements.

```js
const texts = document.querySelectorAll('.content p > span');
const links = document.querySelectorAll('.link-block a');
links.forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', e => {
    texts.forEach(text => text.classList.add('hidden'));
    const id = e.target.getAttribute('href');
    links.forEach(el => {
      el.classList.remove('active');
    });
    e.target.classList.add('active');
    document.querySelector(id).classList.remove('hidden');
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.active {
  color: #f0f;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <section class="content">
    <p>
      <span id="content-1">Sample Text for Content 1.</span>
      <span id="content-2" class="hidden">Sample Text for Content 2.</span>
      <span id="content-3" class="hidden">Sample Text for Content 3.</span>
    </p>
  </section>
  <section class="link-block">
    <a href="#content-1" class="active">Content 1</a>
    <a href="#content-2">Content 2</a>
    <a href="#content-3">Content 3</a>
  </section>
</section>
```

Comment: I see! Thank you.

Comment: @user1896653 - I am glad it helped. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

```
links.forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', e => {
    links.forEach(element => {
      element.classList.remove('active');
    });
    texts.forEach(text => text.classList.add('hidden'));
    const id = e.target.getAttribute('href');
    e.target.classList.add('active');
    document.querySelector(id).classList.remove('hidden');
  }); 
});
```

Comment: yes, it's the correct solution which I've gotten already from @Rayon. Thanks anyway.

Comment: you're welcome. so this answer can be upvoted?